# how to calculate time complexity for loop including an if statement

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, time-complexity

I don't understand how to calculate time complexity. In an if statement, should I count how many times the condition is evaluated or how many times the statements inside it are executed? Therefore, I wrote a code that nests an if statement inside a for loop. Please analyze the time complexity of this code.
here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    n=100;
    for(i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (i == n - 1)
            break;
    }
}
```

the answer is 1 or n?

Comment: In this loop, `i == n` is always false, so the statement inside `if` executes zero times and affects nothing.

Comment: And a loop that always executes 100 times has constant time complexity.

Comment: *"should I count how many times the condition is evaluated or how many times the statements inside it are executed?"*: both. But in this case the second scenario never happens, so you'd count the condition evaluation.

Comment: @lxzb Considering your code. 

`#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i;
    int n = 100;  // Corrected
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == n)
            break;
    }
}
`
The loop runs for n iterations, and within each iteration, there is a constant-time check (if (i == n)) and a potential break statement.
However, the break statement will never be executed because the loop condition is i < n, and the loop increments i by 1 in each iteration.
Therefore, the time complexity of this program is O(n), where n is the value of the variable n.

Comment: The code as shown has a diagnosable error (due to a missing `;`), and complexity calculations are only relevant for code with no diagnosable errors.   Fix that problem, and compile with optimisation, and you may get a surprise - since modern compilers are smart enough to detect that such simple code has no observable effect (no output, etc)  and may remove the loop (and possibly more) entirely.

Comment: It depends on what is the variable, if `n` is user input. Then the time complexity could be O(n) per your updated example. If n is constant, then it's just O(1).

Comment: Typically, to compute the complexity of a loop with a conditional, one counts how often the conditional expression is evaluated. For complexity, it is irrelevant whether the conditional is evaluated much, much faster than the statements that are controlled by the condition. However, if those statements contain loops themselves, things become trickier.

Comment: "should I count how many times the condition is evaluated or how many times the statements inside it are executed?" It depends on your cost model. A normal cost model would have each statement be O(1), so you count the if, and the proportion of the conditioned statements inside.