# Will the time complexity for this loop be O(1) or O(n)?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namesppace std;

int main() {
    int n = 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "hello";
    }
}
```

I think it will be O(n) and not O(1), because the loop performs n iterations. For people saying it's O(1) because n is constant, what if n=1e9? will it still be O(1)? As n is constant?

Comment: Time complexity is measure of if the input goes up, how will the time used go up.  You don't have any input so your program always runs in constant time.  Doesn't matter if it is a nanosecond or a millennium.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "O(1) access time" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697918/what-does-o1-access-time-mean)

Comment: The purpose of estimating time complexity of algorithms is to determine how they scale, usually in order to compare to other algorithms. It becomes a bit nonsensical in your example here.

Comment: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time): "An algorithm is said to be constant time (also written as O(1) time) if the value of T (n) (the complexity of the algorithm) is bounded by a value that does not depend on the size of the input." Nothing here depends on size of input.

Comment: Side notes, do not use `<bits/stdc++.h>` whatever textbook is still using that is not teaching standard C++.  Also using `using namespace std;` is not recommended

Comment: @OP the answer of Nathan is correct however if you would ask the user for input of a number (say N) than your complexity becomes dependent on the input and your complexity would be O(N) (number of loops is linearly dependent on input N)

Comment: [how to calculate time complexity for loop including an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77638453/how-to-calculate-time-complexity-for-loop-including-an-if-statement?noredirect=1)

Comment: The universe is O(1) even though it's been running for about 13.5 billion years.

Comment: Is this a trick question?  Because that code won't compile, so it's complexity is zero.

Comment: *what if n=1e9? will it still be O(1)? as n is constant?* Yes.

Comment: Your question would be more to the point if you better specify of what you exactly want to calculate the time complexity: (a) the for loop only (and considering `n` as an input argument) or (b) of the main function (with `n` being some internal constant). Your question title seems to suggest the former. Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider two examples:

```cpp
void myFunc(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "hello";
    }
}
```

```cpp
void myFunc(int m) {
    int n = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "hello";
    }
}
```

In the first example, the complexity will be `O(n)`, because if you call this function with a variable `n` 10 times larger, the code inside the loop will perform 10 times more iterations.

In the second example, the complexity will be `O(1)`, because the number of commands executed by the code does not depend on the variable passed into the function.

However, in both cases, the complexity could be considered `O(n)`; it's just that in the second case, `n` is a constant, so `O(const) = O(1)`.
(This is just for clarity. You shouldn't say that the complexity is `O(n)` here, if you don't want to confuse the other person)

---

You can also say:

code

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "hello";
}
```

has a complexity of `O(n)`, but if you add initialization of the variable `n`, then the code

```cpp
int n = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "hello";
}
```

has a complexity of `O(1)`.

Comment: That last paragraph is wrong. The `n` in `O(n)` is not the name of a variable; it's just a placeholder. A loop that runs from 0 to q can still be described as `O(n)`, because its duration is proportional to the size of the input.

Comment: the only thing that bothers me is that if i set n=1e10 and run the code, it will be TLE right? so it feels kinda weird to say that tc is O(1)

Comment: @PeteBecker I think that in certain contexts, you can perceive `n` in the expression `O(n)` as a variable. For instance, when there are multiple parameters in a function, its complexity can be equal to `O(n*m)`.

Comment: @SxreaM If you are solving a problem with a time constraint, you might encounter a TLE (Time Limit Exceeded). However, `O(1)` doesn't imply that a task should finish quickly. It means that it always executes within a certain time limit, regardless of the input data.

Comment: @AvidCoder -- um, you're mixing levels of analysis. "The time complexity of a loop that runs up to `n` with a nested loop that runs up to `m` is `O(n*m)`" is a true statement, even if the **implementaiton** of those loops uses `outer_loop_upper_bound` and `inner_loop_upper_bound` as the names of its variables. Time complexity isn't about the code that you write; it's about what that code does.

Comment: @PeteBecker but if the complexity of the algorithm is `O(sqrt(n)mln(m))`, how can one understand which variable relates to what? This can be explicitly specified, but then n and m can simply be regarded as aliases for the actual variable names. It's probably not commonly expressed in a professional environment, but from a mathematical standpoint, I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: @SxreaM -- as AvidCoder says, `O(1)` means only that the run time doesn't **change** when the size of the input changes. It doesn't say anything about what that run time is. `sleep(twenty_four_hours);` sleeps for 24 hours; it's `O(1) because the duration doesn't change with the size of the input, even though it's prohibitively long.

Comment: @AvidCoder -- again, time complexity is about **algorithms**, not about how they're implemented.

Comment: As an external party to this discussion, I have to agree with @AvidCoder. We all usually write `O(n)` without ever defining what `n` is because it is usually obvious (e.g. number of items in a container or integer parameter passed to the algorithm). @AvidCoder is not saying you cannot say your algorithm is `O(n)` is the function uses a variable called `uppper_bound` as its parameter, just that **if it is not obvious what `n` is**, you have to give the precision that `n` corresponds to `upper_bound` in this case.

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree that if there's a constant `C` in the code, no one would say that the time complexity is `O(C*...)`, as it doesn't carry much significance. However, there's nothing conceptually wrong with it. I provided this example simply for a better understanding of the issue.